# Rails undefined method `query=' for #<HTTPI::Request:0x007f914b61f8d0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to integrate a Rails App with ActiveCampaign CRM using the following gem: https://github.com/RushPlay/active_campaign

```
ac = ActiveCampaign::Client.new({:api_method => 'https://website.api-us1.com',:api_key => 'mykey'})
response = ac.contact_sync({ :email => "test@test.com",:first_name => "John",:last_name => "Doe" })
```

The request is unsuccessful and Rails returns this:

```
undefined method `query=' for #<HTTPI::Request:0x007f914b61f8d0>
```

Any idea why this might be? I've been trying to figure it out for a while, and can't get to the bottom of it...

**UPDATE**

I tried updating my HTTPI gem to a newer version (2+) and the original error disappeared, but now I am seeing the following error:

```
757: unexpected token at '<div align="center">

    <div style="font-size:15px; color:#333; padding: 50px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <div style="font-size:33px; padding:12px;">Not Found</div>
        <div>Sorry, this page could not be found.<br />
Please check your link/URL and try again.</div>
    </div>
</div>'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[active_campaign's gemspec](https://github.com/RushPlay/active_campaign/blob/master/active_campaign.gemspec) doesn't specify a `httpi` version, [looking at the commit](https://github.com/savonrb/httpi/commit/207791ac36df6d17a86b421e84020c1709beed69) that added the `query=` method, it looks like it's been in there since 2.0.

Do you have an old (1.x) version of `httpi` in your `Gemfile.lock`?  If you `bundle up httpi`, does it help?

Comment: Hi Nick, I checked my gemfile.lock and found that both savon and wasabi depend on httpi (~> 1.0). I tried bundle up httpi and reset the server but the error is still there...how should I proceed from here? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: If those gems depend on an earlier version of httpi, you'll need to see if you can update those to versions that depend on a newer httpi.  Otherwise you're kind of stuck in some dependency incompatibilities.  You could also look for an older version of active_campaign that uses an older httpi.

Comment: I was able to update my HTTPI gem ..I was calling on an old version of savon, which I changed.... but now I am getting another error...Please see above.

Comment: No clue, looks like you're requesting the wrong page or something.